# Font converted to outline won't fill in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Whenever I convert a font to an outline in Illustrator, it seems to lose the fill colour and I have no idea how to get it back. All tutorials I have read show that after converting, the fill colour should be the shape, but all conversions I have done just leave me with an unfillable outline (I tried applying the colour with the swatches).

Comment: That is odd. All paths in a correctly constructed glyph ought to be entirely closed. (Where did you get such a badly defined font from?) Can you add an image to your post, showing what the outlines of such a character look like? Does Illustrator report its path as "closed"?

Comment: .. Just for clarity's sake: you are definitely **not** accidentally working in "Outline Preview" mode?

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot! I've been battling with this for hours!

Comment: Make it an answer, @Jongware ?

Comment: @Benteh: I really would not mind if the OP deleted it.

Comment: @Rad Lexus: Deleting it opens up the question to be asked again by someone else. My problem was that I was unaware of the feature and therefore unable to make the right search regarding "Outline Preview". If people find this in the future, they will see both your answer and the duplicate question to help them.